# What is php_executable_path in LAMP ubuntu12.04?

Tags: php, wordpress, google-app-engine

I am installing wordpress using Google App Engine and using this command to run the application, app_dir contains app.yaml, php.ini and wordpress:

```
google_appengine/dev_appserver.py app_dir/
```

and getting these errors:

> File "/home/g1m/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/php_runtime.py", line 222, in new_instance
>       self._check_environment(php_executable_path)
>     File "/home/g1m/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/php_runtime.py", line 147, in _check_environment
>       'flag (%s) does not exist.' % php_executable_path)
>   _PHPBinaryError: The path specified with the --php_executable_path flag () does not exist.

I am trying to access the application using this url: localhost:8080 and get following error:

> The path specified with the --php_executable_path flag () does not exist.

Kindly help me to solve this, what is the value of php_executable_path in LAMP as I am using UBUNTU12.04 operating system, is it /etc/php/cgi ?

Kindly let me know where I am doing wrong.

Comment: I figure it out, to know what is executable path install php-cgi binar, https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/gettingstarted/installinglinux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you install it first by doing:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-cgi
```

then locate it by running a search for php-cgi

```
sudo find / -name php-cgi
```

in my case i found it in : /usr/bin/php-cgi

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason for this error is that GAE need to work with cgi not cli. The difference in them is that cli (command line interface) is for standalone application, not for web app (it didn't output html header by default). If php-cgi is installed , you can specify its path like this when you start dev server

```
<PATH_TO_SDK>app_devserver.py --php_executable_path=/usr/bin/php-cgi <your_project_name>
```

If you are not sure, you could search for it like dsb005 suggested.
If it's not installed... hmm... Maybe you miss this one on GAE document :

> HP 5.4 is not packaged on most Linux distributions so it may be easiest to install it from source. On Debian-based Linux systems, you can use the following commands to install PHP 5.4 in such a way that it won't effect any other versions of PHP that you may have installed:

I suggest you follow the instruction on 
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/gettingstarted/installinglinux and see if it works. It's always a pay off when you don't read the manual. I did that sometimes :(